# Javascript "Table Width" Is Changing "Tbody Width"

Tags: javascript

I made a javascript to change many tables width according to the amount of text inside each tables.

---

But my problem is javascript is changing the width of tbody (saw in browser inspect element) not the table width, that's why there is a unnecessary white-space (red color) after the the table (i think because of my bad coding or while loop), please see this fiddle and scroll to the right: http://jsfiddle.net/p9edr8e9/1/
Where is my mistake and how it change width of whole table?

Thanks!

Javascript:

```
var table = document.getElementsByClassName("tabwid");
for (var i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    var j = 0,
        row;
    tabwid = table[i].offsetWidth;
    row = table[i].rows;
    while (row[j++]) {
        var hei = row.offsetHeight;
        while (tabwid < 4000) {
            tabwid += 500;
            table[i].style.width = tabwid + 'px';
            if (row.offsetHeight == hei) {
                table[i].style.width = tabwid - 500 + 'px';
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.table{ overflow-x:auto; line-height:1.4em;}
table{ border-collapse:collapse; display:block; background:#ffaaaa; }
tbody{ background:#aaffaa; }
th{ text-align:center; vertical-align:top; background:#222; color:#eee; padding:16px 8px; font-weight:normal; }
td{ padding:8px; border:1px solid #aaa; }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table">

<table class="tabwid">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
            <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
            <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
            <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
            <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
            <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
            <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
            <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
            <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
            <th>HHH HHH HHH HHH</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
            <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
            <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
            <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
            <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
            <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
            <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
            <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
            <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
            <td>AAA AAA AAA AAA</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
            <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
            <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
            <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
            <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
            <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
            <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
            <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
            <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
            <td>BBB BBB BBB BBB</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
            <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
            <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
            <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
            <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
            <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
            <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
            <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
            <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
            <td>CCC CCC CCC CCC</td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
            <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
            <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
            <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
            <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
            <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
            <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
            <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
            <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
            <td>DDD DDD DDD DDD</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table{ border-collapse:collapse; display:block; background:#ffaaaa; }
```

Please remove the `display: block;` assignment to display the table as what it is: a table. Then you ar going to be fine.

Comment: that will just move extra space to inside cells

Comment: Nope: it makes <tbody> stretch to the width of its <table> container (as it is supposed to do). The extra space comes from the width you calculated and set for the table. As it is standard, the width is equaly split up over the columns (since they all have the same content and nothing else is defined). If you algorithm would define a smaller width, the empty space would be smaller as well. Usually tables just take the space they need. So if a table perfectly fitted to its contents is what you are trying to achieve, you actually do not have to do anything at all.

Comment: ok, but is there any other way to make table compact other than `display:block;` because when i remove it the visible table goes from 1680px to 2542px !!!

Comment: as stated before: a table is usually compact by itself since it does not cover more space than needed. What makes it expand that havily is your javascript. you never actually stated what you try to achieve. So I can only guess. If you want the table to be as compact as possible without any line breaks you could set white-space: nowrap; for the tables.

Comment: thanks I removed javascript and display block, and added white-space:nowrap (tried before but unable to use <br/> tag) Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/p9edr8e9/10/ .  Now i can use br tag. Please UpVote Me.